# ¿Error al cargar imagen con Dropzone js en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en la cual se pueden subir imagenes y para ello uso el plugin dropzone js, mi problema es que al subir la imagen me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy instanciando dropzone en un div.

adjunto el codigo de la vista:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.css">



@section('contenido')

<div>

<p>Album: {{ $foto->id }}</p>

</div>
<form action="{{ route('fotos') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {{ csrf_field() }}  

<div class="form-group">


//div que utilizo para el dropzone
<div class="dropzone">



</div>

<div class="form-group">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cargar</button>

    </div>
</form>
</div>

@stop
```

Codigo donde inicializo dropzone:

```
@push('scripts')

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>






<script >




var myDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {

// Ruta especificada
url: '/fotos',

// con esta sentencia le decimos a dropzone que solo acepte archivos de imagen y con el * le decimos que acepte imagenes con cualquier extension
acceptedFiles: 'image/*',

// con esta sentencia le definimos a dropzone la restriccion de tamaño del archivo a subir en Mega Bytes
maxFilesize: 2,

// con esta sentencia restringimos la cantidad de archivos que se pueden subir
// maxFiles: 1,

paramName: 'photo',



headers: {

    // verificacion del token
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'

},

// esta sentencia cambia el mensaje por defecto que aparece en la caja de dropzone
dictDefaultMessage : 'Arrastra las imagenes aqui para subirlas'

});

myDropzone.on('error', function(file , res){

console.log(res);

});

// con esta sentencia le decimos a dropzone que no se active automaticamente, solo cuando le demos clic
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

</script>


@endpush
```

Codigo de la ruta establecida para el formulario :

```
Route::get('fotos','FotoController@upload')->name('fotos');
```

Funcion upload del FotoController:

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
    {

        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $fileUrl = $file->store('public');

        return 'imagen guardada';



    }
```

Alguna idea de que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer solo es problema de rutas.

Cuando se utiliza rutas de laravel en `script` no es recomendable escribir solo la ruta, tendrias que utilizar siempre(es lo que recomiendo) una funcion de rutas, las cuales pueden ser `url()`,`route()` y hasta para importar documentos es recomendable utilizar funciones como: `public_path()`, `Storage::get()` o `asset()`.

Entonces al parecer tu problema radica en la inizalizacion de tu **dropzone** especificamente en la ruta o url:

```
url: '/fotos',//esta linea estaria mal, lo digo sin probarlo solo por experiencia
```

Tendria que estar de la siguiente manera:

```
url: '{{url("fotos")}}',
```

Ó en todo cado como tienes definido el `->name('fotos')` en tu ruta tambien puedes llamarlo con `route`.

```
url: '{{route("fotos")}}',
```

Otro error parece ser la respuesta, muchas librerias se adaptan a una comunicacion standar de respuestas, asi que es hora de empezar a acostumbrase a enviar respuesta con codigos como el `success` y el `error`.

En tu caso sera algo como esto:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{

    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $fileUrl = $file->store('public');
    // algunas cosas mas para saber si se subio correctamente y luego...
    if( $si_se_subio_correctamete ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }

}
```

Otro problema es la confusion en el tipo de ruta, en tus rutas en `get` y en tu formulario esta `post`.

Para subir de forma correcta tu imagen te recomiendo el siguiente codigo:

```
    $file = Input::file('photo');//foto es tu variable de formulario

    $extension = File::extension($file['name']);
    $directory = path('public').'uploads/'.sha1(time());
    $filename = sha1(time().time()).".{$extension}";

    $upload_success = Input::upload('file', $directory, $filename);

    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
```

Espero que es te ayude.

Comment: Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda, agregue los cambios y aun asi me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: @KevinBurbano, ahora lo veo mejor, es tu ruta que esta en `get` y tu formulario es de tipo `post`, eh ahi otro horror perdon error, razon por la cual no encuentra la ruta especificada

Comment: Exacto me acabo de dar cuenta tambien, ya lo corregi y funciono tu solucion, ahora me tira es un problema al tratar de guardarla me dice Call to a member function store() on null.

Comment: Las imagenes se guardan, en la carpeta pero en la pagina me muestra ese error.